# How to identify the super (parent) heading level of the current heading

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Lets Suppose i have some headings on the page like this

```
<h1 class="head-1"> Title 1 </h1>
    <h2 class="head-2"> title 2 </h2>
        <h3 class="head-3"> title 2.1 </h3>
        <h3 class="head-3"> title 2.2 </h3>
    <h2 class="head-2"> title 3 </h2>
        <h3 class="head-3"> title 3.1</h3>
        <h3 class="head-3"> title 3.2</h3>
```

So let's say i found element using `//h3[text()= "title 3.2"]`.

Now, i want to get the super element of current heading.

For example i want to do something like `headingElement.getSuperHeading();//this method will have code to find the super heading`

Does anybody know how can i retrieve the super heading element from current element?

Comment: https://testingrepository.com/how-to-get-the-parent-of-an-element/  https://jitblog.net/get-the-parent-node-of-the-current-selenium-webelement/

Comment: @Ahmet OZKESEK, This logic wont work here because heading tags are not container tag.

Comment: What you mean `super heading` ? Refers to your element example `//h3[text()= "title 3.2"]` which the part you want achieve?

Comment: @frianH, I want to get the <h2> element which is super of <h3>, i hope this will help you now.

Comment: @MadhavSaraf Does this answer your question? `//h3[text()= " title 3.2"]//preceding-sibling::h2[1]` ?

Comment: Yes i can convinced myself with this answer but this is not actually perfect answer this wont fetch super heading if it is inside some wrapper div's, but yeah its good one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath axes https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Try this
`//h3[text()= "title 3.2"]/parent::*`

Comment: As i said before `::parent` or `../` this xpath trick will directly points to parent and not the parent heading because heading it not a container tag like <div> <span>, etc